# How to shift lines down in vi

Tags: bash, line, vi

Assuming i have ^ delimited files like this: (note ^M is getting from ctrl+ v plus "enter", while "^" is just shift+6)

```
1^2^3^M1^2^3^M1^2^3^M
```

Is there any quick way to make the file into the following?

```
1^2^3
1^2^3
1^2^3
```

Thanks!

Comment: `!!tr '\r' '\n'` would work — map carriage return `\r` to newline `\n` with the transliterate program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find an answer!

```
%s/^M/\r/g
```

^M is obtained from ctrl+ v plus "enter"

Comment: why `\r` and not `\n`?